# Error Another setup is already running when trying to install TDS on VS2019

Tags: tds, visual-studio

I have a Sitecore 9.3 XP0 instance installed on my machine and now I'm trying to set up the TDS v6.0.0.31 on my Visual Studio 2019 v16.10.1, but whenever I install it the following error is thrown:

```
    Select Continue to install Visual Studio while the other install is running. This might cause 
    problems with other parts of the installation.

    Select Retry to continue with the Visual Studio install once the other install has completed.

    Select Cancel to cancel the Visual Studio install.
    30/08/2021 10:01:13 - Pre-check verification failed with warning(s) :  
    AnotherInstallationRunning.
    30/08/2021 10:01:13 - Erro de Instalação: System.AggregateException: Um ou mais erros. ---> 
    System.OperationCanceledException: Pre-check verification failed with warning(s) :  
    AnotherInstallationRunning. ---> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.CanceledByPrecheckException: 
    Pre-check verification failed with warning(s) :  AnotherInstallationRunning.
    --- Fim do rastreamento de pilha de exceções internas ---
    em Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.PrecheckManager.RunPrechecks(PrecheckParameters 
    precheckParameters, VariableCollection properties)
    em Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.RunPrecheck(String destination, Product product, 
    ExecuteAction action, IWindowsRestartManager rmService, ITelemetryOperation installOperation, 
    InstallOperation install)
    em Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.Install(Product product, String destination, 
    CancellationToken token)
    em Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.SetupEngineService.<Install>b__14_0()
    em System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
    em System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
    --- Fim do rastreamento de pilha de exceções internas ---
    em System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
    em System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken 
 cancellationToken)
    em Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.SetupEngineService.Install()
    em 

    Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.PerformSetupEngineInstall(InstallableExtensionImpl extension, Boolean installPerMachine, Boolean isPackComponent, IDictionary`2 extensionsInstalledSoFar, List`1 extensionsUninstalledSoFar, IInstalledExtensionList modifiedInstalledExtensionsList, IProgress`1 progress, InstallFlags installFlags, AsyncOperation asyncOp, Version targetedVsVersion, IInstalledExtension& newExtension)
       em Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.InstallInternal(InstallableExtensionImpl extension, InstallFlags installFlags, IDictionary`2 extensionsInstalledSoFar, List`1 extensionsUninstalledSoFar, IInstalledExtensionList modifiedInstalledExtensionsList, AsyncOperation asyncOp, IProgress`1 progress, Version targetedVsVersion)
       em Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.BeginInstall(IInstallableExtension installableExtension, InstallFlags installFlags, AsyncOperation asyncOp, Version targetedVsVersion)
       em Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.InstallWorker(IInstallableExtension extension, InstallFlags installFlags, AsyncOperation asyncOp)
    ---> (Exceção Interna N° 0) System.OperationCanceledException: Pre-check verification failed with warning(s) :  AnotherInstallationRunning. ---> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.CanceledByPrecheckException: Pre-check verification failed with warning(s) :  AnotherInstallationRunning.
       --- Fim do rastreamento de pilha de exceções internas ---
       em Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.PrecheckManager.RunPrechecks(PrecheckParameters precheckParameters, VariableCollection properties)
       em Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.RunPrecheck(String destination, Product product, ExecuteAction action, IWindowsRestartManager rmService, ITelemetryOperation installOperation, InstallOperation install)
       em Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.Install(Product product, String destination, CancellationToken token)
       em Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.SetupEngineService.<Install>b__14_0()
       em System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
       em System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()<---
```

I've already done the steps suggested in the following link but even after kill all msiexec.exe running processes I'm still getting the same error.

[I receive the error “Another setup is already running](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/support/vs2015/receive-error-another-setup-already-running-please-wait-finish-trying/)

Comment: did you try to close all instances of VS 2019 and try to install the extension again ?

Comment: @VladIobagiu
Yes, I had no Visual Studio instances running.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem and after the TDS installation finished and before the VSIX installation I ended all msiexec processes and after that I did the VSIX installation. With these steps I was able to install TDS and the extension on VS2019.

Comment: It worked nicely for me, but before trying again I had to run the TDS installation wizard again and choose the Remove Installation option, after that, I restarted my machine and then I killed any msiexec.exe process and then I run the TDS .msi installer again, but be careful, after the TDS is installed don't execute the Visual Studio Extension installation, before doing that, be sure that the all msiexec.exe processes from TDS installation were killed, just after that you can proceed with the installation of the extension into Visual Studio (.vsix file).

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem with visual studio 2017. Did not work after ending all msiexec  processes.

After updating an update through Visual Studio Installer and rebooting system, issue got resolved.